# Using symbolic link on directory with contents

Tags: filesystems, symlink

I'm working on a Debian machine with a bunch of different filesystems and I'm trying to manipulate a large amount of data in MySQL. I've run out of room in my home directory, but there's a ton of empty space in other systems (particularly one that's located in /srv). I want to make it so that /var/lib/mysql (the directory that stores MySQL data) seems to still be in its rightful location, but all of its data is stored in /srv/mysql. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

First, move or copy `/var/lib/mysql` to `/srv/mysql`.

```
$ mv -i /var/lib/mysql /srv
$ cp -ir /var/lib/mysql /srv
```

You may want to use a bind mount instead of a symbolic link. Bind mounts won't break in special roots.

```
$ mkdir /var/lib/mysql
$ mount --bind /srv/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

if you decide to use a symbolic link, remove the old `/var/lib/mysql` directory and run the following.

```
$ ln -s /srv/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: When I try that ln -s command I get: "ln: failed to create symbolic link `/var/lib/mysql/mysql': File exists". It may have something to do with the fact that /var/lib/mysql/mysql is a directory, but that seems like an error that shouldn't be happening regardless.

Comment: You have to remove the old directory first. Make sure its contents have been copied to the new location (`/srv/mysql`) and run `rm -r /var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: It seems like it worked, but MySQL no longer recognizes any of the databases and gives me an Error 1006 errno 2 when I try to make one.

Comment: Try using a bind mount instead. Delete the symlink (`rm /var/lib/mysql`), make a new directory there (`mkdir /var/lib/mysql`), and bind mount the new directory on the old one (`mount --bind /srv/mysql /var/lib/mysql`).

Comment: You'll have to add the mount to your `/etc/fstab` file for it to mount on boot. This line should work: `/srv/mysql /var/lib/mysql bind defaults,bind 0 0`. You could also change your mysql configuration to point to the new directory. Though, that may cause problems if you're using administration utilities that expect to find your mysql data at `/var/lib/mysql`.